How to use border patch
I've patched bar-height, center, grid and gridnav without problems, but when i path border neither the -bw 8 option nor border_width= 8 do anything. I apply patches with patch -p1 < path_to_patch.diff.
I've tried only patching center and border to see if i could get it to work but i'm not having any success.
I've oploaded to my github dmenu patched with only center and border (https://github.com/PatrickStanding/mydmenu/tree/my_dmenu)
edit: the same install draws the border on my arch netbook but not my popos 22.04 lst x11 desktop.
My Config.
static int topbar = 1;              
static int centered = 0;                   
static int min_width = 500; 
static const int user_bh = 5;

static const char *fonts[] = {"FiraMono Nerd Font:size=12"};
static const char *prompt      = NULL;
static const char *colors[SchemeLast][2] = {
    /*     fg         bg       */
    [SchemeNorm] = { "#cdd6f4", "#303446" },
    [SchemeSel] = { "#1e1e2e", "#99d1db" },
    [SchemeOut] = { "#000000", "#89dceb" },
};
static unsigned int lines      = 0;
static unsigned int columns    = 0;

static const char worddelimiters[] = " ";

static unsigned int border_width = 5;

